# Should I refer to North Koreans and South Koreans "same people" or "the same people"?

Tags: articles

Are North Koreans and South Koreans "same people" or "the same people"? Which is correct: *the same* or just *same*, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the definite article there:

> North Koreans and South Koreans are the same people.

**Edit**

*Same* without the article is often used in a telegraphic style (one that omits extra words for the sake of brevity), such as product orders:

> "You requested 52 greeting cards: will ship same within 4 days."

In this case it functions as a demonstrative pronoun, whose antecedent is the cards mentioned. Another way to say that is

> "You requested 52 greeting cards: we will ship those to you within 4 days."

It fine to use either, but *same* in that context is a conventional usage.

Comment: why? is there any rule or just that you have to use it when talking about people?

Comment: *Same* is never used without *the*. [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/same). The only exception is where it is jargon/shorthand, and even then it usually has *the*.

Comment: "The only exception is where it is jargon/shorthand" an example would be nice.

Comment: One example is when *same* is used as part of an adjective phrase, like in "The company offers a same day service." Note that the article in this case refers all the way forward to *service*, and that some people insist on a hyphen when writing *same-day*.

Comment: *Same* without the article is often used in a telegraphic style (one that omits extra words for the sake of brevity), such as product orders: "You requested 52 greeting cards: will ship same within 4 days."

Comment: But even if i use "The company offers [b]the[/b]  same day service." and "You requested 52 greeting cards: will ship [b]the[/b] same within 4 days."  in the examples above,they are correct, right?

Comment: I would not use *the same* in that context. The usage without the article functions, in those cases, as a kind of demonstrative pronoun referring to an antecedent: in this case, *52 greeting cards.*

Comment: In the greeting card case, the technically correct form is still *the same*, though it will be understood without the article: in the service case, *same day* is an adjectival phrase, (and IMO you still need an article, *a same day service*).